# Head First Java program explanation

Tags: java

my program and question are below

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            while ( x < 5 ) {
                y = x - y;
                System.out.println(x + "" + y);
                x = x+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

So output for this is 00 11 21 32 42. I understand what happens when x is even but what when x is odd? Let's move to step 2 and make x=1, then we get

```
 y=1-y 
2y=1
 y=1/2
```

For me output should be like 11/2 or sth like that
So how the hell output for this is 11? Do we use approximation? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Then we get `y=1-y 2y=1 y=1/2` ... No, you get `y=1-0`. Don't ignore the fact that y=0 on that point.

Comment: You have to learn that a = in programming doesn't has the same meaning as a = in math. Here (in programming) a = is an operator to set values to variables. Thus meaning the variable on the left hand side of the = operator gets the value that is derived through the term on the right hand side. You can't rearrange it like you would do it in math.

Answer (score 5):

No. You understand it wrong. You are doing math keeping the fact aside that evaluation of Java expression.

```
  y = x - y;
```

means

```
y= 1-0;
```

Which is

```
y = 1
```

Comment: In other words, this is assigning a value to a variable. This isn't algebra.

Comment: @Arc676 But understanding this is hard. Especially for beginners. I taught many beginners in basic programming (C or Java) and almost every time they were misled by the fact that = has a different meaning in math.

Comment: @Aron_dc On the other hand, what OP think also true. But the fact is that it is hard to believe that the same thing works differently in places. :) We have to make them understand.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing off with your code, the result is correct.  When `x` is 1, we set `y` to be equal to `x` - `y`.  That means `x` and `y` are both 1, as 1 - 0 is 1.  Remember that `a = b` in programming is an assignment and does not imply equality.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious? By **"="** you assigning new value into variable.

```
    x = 0, y = 0
    y = 0 - 0 = 0
    print x y -> 0 0
    x = 1, y = 0
    y = 1 - 0 = 1
    print x y -> 1 1 
    x = 2, y = 1
    y = 2 - 1 = 1
    print x y -> 2 1
```

etc...

Comment: The fact that the OP did ask this question leads to: No it isn't obvious ;-)